# Show that $(|x| - R)^p \leq |x|^p - R^p$

Tags: inequality

This inequality was found in a book that I'm reading, and the author states it without proof.
Now, let $R >0$, $|x|\geq R$ and $+\infty>p\geq 1$. Therefore:
$$
(|x| - R)^p \leq |x|^p - R^p
$$

How can one prove this inequality?

Comment: $(a+b)^{p} \geq a^{p}+b^{p}$ fro $a, b \geq 0$ and $p \geq 1$.

Comment: I don't see how it follow...

Comment: $|x| = (|x| - R) + R$

Comment: Add $R^p$ to both sides. On the right hand side, write $|x|^p$ as $((|x| - R) + R)^p$. Expand the right hand side. You get the two things on the left, plus (if $p \gt 1$) a whole bunch of other stuff, all of which is > 0.